# How to find the minimum number of groups needed for grouping a list of elements?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

For example:

There is a list of elements, e.g. a sorted integer list {1,2,3,4,6,8,11}.

I want to find the minimum number of groups, in which each member in the group have a 
qualified difference between each other, e.g. less than or equal to 2 to each other.

In this case, we can see the answer should be 4, and one possible solution is {1,2,3},{4,6},{8},{11}.

How to write the algorithm to find the minimum number?

Furthermore, we can consider this in 2 dimension:

There is a list of points {(3,3),(3,6),(6,9)}. What is the minimum number of squares with length 3 I will need to use to cover all those points? The answer should be 2 here. But how to find it by programming?

I am asking this question for solving the question [Square Fields](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/32004/dashboard#s=p1) in Google Code Jam Practice Contest, but any answer solving the first part of this question is good enough for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1-D: Sort the elements by ascending order, and greedily form groups by setting the new group's left bound as the smallest element not yet covered by any group.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think it can be solved in such a simple method. That's great =D

Comment: This solution is great following on a good way to consider the 2-D problem is to follow @timrau's solution but substitute left for left AND UPPER.. goodluck (for an exercise consider {(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(6,6),(8,8),(11,11)})